# Pass Parameter through URL in Magento

Tags: magento, controller, param

My URL is as follows:

```
http://exaample.ae/vendorms/artist/portfolio/name/emavens/id/1
```

vendorms is front name

artist is controller name

portfolio is action name

```
echo $name = $this->getRequest ()->getParam ( 'name' );
echo $id = $this->getRequest ()->getParam ( 'id' );
```

output is :

emavens

all

When I hit this url:

```
  http://exaample.ae/vendorms/artist/portfolio/name/emavens/id/1/key/dhd363eg633eh
```

output is :

emavens

1

Please somebody explain me ???

Comment: Try `print_r($this->getRequest()->getParam());`

Answer (score 1):

try to print this under the controller action

```
print_r('<pre>');
print_r($this->getRequest()->getParams());
exit;
```

Let me know what was the print.

Best,
Alejandro.

Comment: something like this Array ( [name] => emavens [id] => 1 )